# How to print more variables into file?

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to print one value of variable but I have a problem with more variables into one line.

```
file = open("values","w+")
file.write(str(q+q_krok+omega+omega_krok+e+e_krok))
```

The desired files values:

```
1-8-9-9-6-6
```

I would like to print values of 6 variables into file and between them put some value, for instance -. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the values into a string, then simply write that string to file.

```
values = <whatever your values are, as a string>

with open(“values.txt”, “w”) as f: 
    f.write(values)
```

If you have a list of values, you could create the string by using a join statement.

```
val_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
values = '-'.join(val_list)
```

If you have a specific set of values stored in different vars, you could use an f-string.

```
values = f'{val1}-{val2}-{val3}-{val4}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much and what does f mean in the third code?

Comment: The f is an f-string, introduced in python 3.6 I think. If you're on an earlier version of 3 you can just use the `format` option - `values = '{}-{}-{}'.format(val1, val2, val3)`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
li = [q,q_krok,omega,omega_krok,e,e_krok]
values = '-'.join(li)
with open("values_file", "w") as f: 
    f.write(values)
```

You can even do it this way:

```
file = open("values_file","w+")
file.write(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the values into a list, like:

```
items = [1,8,9,9,6,6]
with open('test.txt, 'r') as f:
    for elem in items[:-1]:                       -- for each element instead of last
        print(elem, end="-")                      -- print the value and the separator
    if (len(items) > 1):
        print(items[-1])                         -- print last item without separator
```

A very well-made tutorial about reading/writing to files in python can be watched here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh2ebFW8OYM&t=1264s